# Problem with a function returning an empty object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, react-router-dom, mern

I am working on a project which lets users click on Travel Tour "Cards" and be sent to a new page where all details concerning that specific card gets displayed to the user!

I have a problem with this specific functionality where my getTour function doesnt return the object details connected to the url id parameter which gets sent from the previous component (The card).

As you can see in the JSX part i call the function, and specify the property in the returned object to be displayed on the screen.

I just get an empty object back so no data is coming from the returned function!

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import cities from '../data.json';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Tour() {
  // getting the id url parameter sent from the Card Component.
  const { id } = useParams();

  const idAsNumber = Number(id);
  const getTour = () => {
    let tour = {};
    // Iterate over the Data, finding the specific object with this id.
    tour = cities.map(city => {
        city.tours.map(tour => {
          if (tour.id === idAsNumber) {
            return tour;
          }
        });
      }
    );
    return tour;
  };
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <Container sx={{ width: 900 }}>
      <Typography variant="h3" component="h1" marginTop={3}>
      {getTour().name}
      </Typography>
      <Box marginTop={3} sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <img
          src={getTour().image}
          height={325}
```

Comment: You need a `return` statement inside your first `map`

Comment: Your `getTour` function returns an array, and arrays don’t generally have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Map isn't returning anything:

thefollowing:

```
tour = cities.map(city => {
    city.tours.map(tour => {
        if (tour.id === idAsNumber) {
            return tour;
        }
    });
});
```

should be changed to either:

```
tour = cities.map(city => {
    return city.tours.map(tour => {
        if (tour.id === idAsNumber) {
            return tour;
        }
    });
});
```

or alternatively, use brackets instead of braces:

```
tour = cities.map(city => (
    city.tours.map(tour => {
        if (tour.id === idAsNumber) {
            return tour;
        }
    });
));
```

Comment: I still has problem with displaying the content on the screen in JSX though but that is probably another thing in itself

Answer (score 0):

Based on the function signature and comment, `getTour` should return an object, not an array. [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array.

You very likely should be using [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if that's really what you are wanting to do, e.g. `// Iterate over the Data, finding the specific object with this id`.

If translated into English you are saying: "Search the `cities` array for a city that includes a `tours` array where *some* tour matches `id`.

```js
const { id } = useParams();

const getTour = () => {
  // Iterate over the Data, finding the specific object with this id.
  return cities.find(city => {
    return city.tours.some(tour => String(tour.id) === id);
  });
};
```

Keep in mind that `Array.prototype.find` returns [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#return_value) when no matching array element is found via the predicate function. The UI should handle this.

Examples:

```
return (
  <Container sx={{ width: 900 }}>
    <Typography variant="h3" component="h1" marginTop={3}>
      {getTour()?.name}
    </Typography>
    <Box marginTop={3} sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <img
        src={getTour()?.image}
        height={325}
```

or

```
const tour = getTour();

return (
  <Container sx={{ width: 900 }}>
    <Typography variant="h3" component="h1" marginTop={3}>
      {tour?.name}
    </Typography>
    <Box marginTop={3} sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <img
        src={tour?.image}
        height={325}
```

You can memoize the `tour` value using the `useMemo` hook and the `id` path parameter as a dependency, if necessary, `tour` is only only computed on the initial render or when the `id` value changes.

```js
const tour = useMemo(() => () => {
  // Iterate over the Data, finding the specific object with this id.
  return cities.find(city => {
    return city.tours.some(tour => String(tour.id) === id);
  });
}, [id]);

...
```

Comment: This was very well explained and made everything a lot clearer for me, thanks for helping out. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @DanielB What bad English? :) I thought your post was perfectly intelligible. Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!